# How to implement it using Multi threading in python?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am new to python and I want to understand how I can perform this operation using multi threading as the data is too large this operation is taking lot of time.

I have around 2500+ columns in spark dataframe df_my

```
d=[]
for x in df_my.columns:
  
    null_cnt= df_my.filter(df_my[x].isNotNull()).count()
    zero_cnt= df_my.filter(df_my[x]==0).count()
    fill_percent= str(((null_cnt)/total)*100)
    zero_percent= str(((zero_cnt)/null_cnt)*100)
    d.append({'Feature_name' : x,
              'Fillrate': fill_percent,
              'zero_percent':zero_percent })
    
final=spark.createDataFrame(d)
f_pandas=final.toPandas()
f_pandas.to_excel("output_pandas.xlsx")
```

Can anyone please help me in doing this using multi threading?

Comment: Is `df_my` a Pandas dataframe or a Spark thing or something? `isNotNull` is definitely not a Pandas thing.

Comment: @AKX It's a spark dataframe

Comment: I think you should do it distributedly in Spark then rather than attempting to thread it on one machine.

Comment: Can you please explain properly? how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use .parallel_apply function from pandarallel to do multiprocessing. Take a look at [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandaral-lel-a-simple-and-efficient-tool-to-parallelize-your-pandas-operations-on-all-your-cpus-bb5ff2a409ae) link

Comment: You can try using Pandas UDFs to parallelize your Python code in a Spark environment

Comment: Can you please explain me by using my code here? it would be easy for me to understand as I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a thread pool and use it for running spark tasks in parallel.
Please note that you need to use Fair scheduler for spark using below configuration :

```
conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
```

Please see this link to get the python code -
[Using python multithreading in Pyspark to write data to table in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814156/using-python-multithreading-in-pyspark-to-write-data-to-table-in-parallel)